# Selenium:With selelenium RC can we scroll the scrollbar up or down of browser.

Tags: selenium

Can we use Selenium RC to move the browser's scroll bar up or down?

Comment: A better way to word the question might be, "Can you use Selenium RC to move the browser's scroll bar up or down?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to a scroll bar for the entire browser, as opposed to a scroll bar for a piece of the page (e.g. a list) in the browser.

I do not believe there is a Selenium API for moving the browser's scroll bar up or down.   However, you can use the RemoteWebdriver.executeScript method to run some JavaScript that will scroll the entire browser.  In JavaScript, you can use the ScrollBy and ScrollTo methods on the DOM Window object.

Comment: Thansk a lot. I can use :selenium.getEval("window.scrollTo(0,0)");